# Async UI update

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, async-await

I started programming just few month ago so I am a pure beginner
but I needed a math app with Heavy probability calculation and an UI to view/interact so I searched around and found C#.net was the best way... fantastic power...

It will help me a lot to progress if I am able do this  :

**Wpf window with textbox, in textbox a number is printed each time the calculation is done but the Ui should respond everytime**

I tried to do it using latest net 4.5 because the app need to be fast (so use the **most recent tech and not timer or background task**)

and it work but the Ui is stuck and cannot move (because of my bad access to the text box I think)

If guys could help me it will be great and I thank you all because I learned a lot with your posts!

Here is my wrong newbie code

```
private Random rng;
public MainWindow()
{
    rng = new Random();
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run((Func<Task>) Calc);
}
private async Task Calc()
{
    while (true)
    {
        textBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke
             (DispatcherPriority.Normal
              , new Action(delegate() 
                 { 
                     textBox1.Text = rng.NextDouble().ToString(); 
                 }
                          )
              );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're tightlooping, admittedly in a non-UI-thread, but adding a bazillion delegates to invoke *in* the UI thread... so your UI is just too busy.

*All* your work is basically going on in the UI thread at the moment - you're not even computing `rng.NextDouble()` in the background thread.

Also note that you've got an `async` method without an `await` expression, which should have triggered a compiler warning - you should take heed of that.

You say you don't want to use a "background task" - but that's exactly what you *are* doing by calling `Task.Run`.

Now I'm assuming your *real* code doesn't actually just need to create random numbers. What does your *real* calculation code look like, and which thread does it occur in?

Comment: maybe I misspoke I just dont want to use the old background task and timer available in old windows form to be able to get all the power of new 4.5 framework
the calculation code should run in a separate thread than the Ui
and each time a new number is available send it to the Ui which should never be stuck

the code is just a csv download (one thread) and the calculation

Comment: @analystLp: If you're already running the calculation code in a separate thread, then I'm not sure async/await is really what you need. So long as you use `Dispatcher.Invoke`, you should already be fine - if you're not overloading the UI thread as your sample does.

Comment: ok then I will continue to learn how to create a true background calculation thread which send number with dispatcher thank you !

Comment: Ok I think I have be able to do it the right way with the following code because start() method works while RunSynchronously() doesn't... too bad I am not good enough to use the new c#5.0 async and await keyword for now :p

    Task task = new Task(new Action(Calc));
task.Start();
        
        private void Calc()
        {
            rng = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                textBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { textBox1.Text = rng.NextDouble().ToString(); }));
            }
        }

Comment: @analystLp: That code is *still* tightlooping. How do you expect the UI to do anything when you're sending it a constant stream of random numbers? It doesn't sound like async is really a good fit for what you're doing here, although you haven't really explained enough about what you're doing to say for sure.

Comment: In the real code calc is an intensive process so the drawing is perfect ! my goal was just to run it in another thread without using background task control !

Comment: @analystLp: But that's the problem - in your repro you're *not* doing much in the other thread. You're just constantly telling the UI to do something... so obviously it's going to be busy.

Comment: Ok and can you show me the code to be sure the task is running in another thread?

Comment: @analystLp: You're already doing it with `Task.Run`. Or you could use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The main thing is to *only* use `Dispatcher.Invoke` with the bit of code which *needs* to run in the UI thread.